# What is a goal when running a Maven/Wicket project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, wicket

I'm trying to learn Wickets, I've managed to install the jars so I have no errors on my code, I have installed and started Tomcat, and I can get to this point:

[image: Error]

What do I put in the goal section? What exactly is the goal?

I also get the error of pass the file name as a parameter, I go into the file arguments and it just throws a ClassDefNotFoundException.

Thanks in advance! And kudos to anyone who has managed to get Wicket to work..

Comment: try the goals `clean install` and what do you mean by file arguments?

Comment: When I try and run the program, in red writing it says in the Console to pass the file name as a parameter, and then gives me classnotfound. I've used the build>Maven clean and maven build, but they're not working.

Comment: @liloka are you passing any file as an argument?

Comment: The [Wicket quickstart page](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) contains a Start.java. This should provide you with an example of how you can run a Wicket project with an embedded jetty server. What are you trying to achieve? Your code looks like it only contains a panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type something like `jetty:run` I guess it would launch the configured `Jetty` server (available in almost all Wicket archetypes)

Comment: Also there is Embedded jetty server under test source folder. You can run it like a Java Application